# How do I draw $\cos^2{(\frac{\pi}{L}x)}$ on the interval $[-L,L]$?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I tried plotting $\cos^2{(\frac{\pi}{L}x)}$ with a couple of different values for $L$ on my computer to get an intuitive feeling for what the function looks like.
I.e:
$L=0.1$
[image: $L=0.1$]
$L=2$
[image: $L=2$]
$L=10$
[image: $L=10$]

What I noticed is that $L$ results plots the same graph as $-L$.
But how can I formalize the drawings for all values of $L$?
What would be a sufficient way to approach this?

Comment: What do you mean by "formalize the drawings"?

Comment: Maybe that was a bad sentence. How can I plot this for the entire interval $[-L,L]$?

Comment: Well you need only worry about one half the interval because cosine is even, hence so is the square of cosine. If you can plot one half the other is a mirror image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a dimensionless variable, $\textit{e.g.}$ $\xi=x/L$ with $\xi\in[-1,1]$. Therefore all your graphs will fit within this interval whatever $L$ is.

You will have then:
$$f(\xi)=\cos^2{(\xi\pi)} \qquad \xi\in[-1,1]$$

Comment: Thanks for you help! But, I don't get one thing; since $x$ can take any value, how can we limit xi to only $[-1,1]$?

Comment: You asked for some function to draw within the interval $[-L,L]$. For that reason, after the change of variable to $\xi$ you can verify that the limits for $\xi$ are obtained from this definition $\xi=x/L$, which takes tha values $-1$ and $1$ for $x=-L$ and $x=L$ respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The graphs all have the following properties: 
 at $x=0$, $\cos^2(\pi x/L)=1$,
 at $x=\pm L/2$, $\cos^2(\pi x/L)=0$,
 at $x=\pm L$, $\cos^2(\pi x/L)=1$, and the rest is just filled in by periodic continuation.